# MySQL stored procedure or dynamic view

Tags: mysql, excel, stored-procedures, view, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement to run a dynamic pivot query across three tables

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'max(case when division_id = ', dp.division_id, ' then process_name end) AS ', d.division_shortName, ' '
    )
) INTO @sql
FROM 
    erp_divisionProcess dp LEFT JOIN erp_division d ON d.division_id = dp.division_id;
SET @sql = concat('SELECT ', @sql, 'FROM (
    SELECT d.division_id, p.process_name, X.rnk
    FROM erp_division d
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT dp.division_id, dp.process_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM erp_divisionProcess A WHERE dp.division_id = A.division_id AND dp.process_id < A.process_id) AS rnk
    FROM erp_divisionProcess dp) X ON X.division_id = d.division_id
    LEFT JOIN erp_BusinessProcess p ON p.process_id = X.process_id 
) x
GROUP BY rnk');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

which produces a pivoted dataset like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+-------+
| PBL             | PLI             | PMI        | PBT        | PBP          | PBI        | PBTL       | PRDT  |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+-------+
| Sales           | Human Resources | Production | Purchasing | Sales        | Purchasing | Purchasing | Sales |
| Human Resources | Purchasing      | NULL       | NULL       | Purchasing   | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  |
| Purchasing      | Finance         | NULL       | NULL       | Distribution | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  |
| Distribution    | NULL            | NULL       | NULL       | Production   | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  |
| Production      | NULL            | NULL       | NULL       | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  |
| Finance         | NULL            | NULL       | NULL       | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

I'd like the resulting dataset to be available to pull into Excel, but MS Query throws and error when I try and run the full statement.  I believe I can't create a view from the prepared statement, so how can I have the query result available without having to retype (copy and paste) it every time and get the results out of MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *I believe I can't create a view from the prepared statement, so how can I have the query result available without having to retype (copy and paste)*

You can create a `view` using Prepared Queries.

Try following change in your code:

```
-- SET @sql = concat('SELECT ', @sql, 'FROM (
SET @sql = concat( 'CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM (
    SELECT d.division_id, p.process_name, X.rnk
    FROM erp_division d
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT dp.division_id, dp.process_id, 
                      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM erp_divisionProcess A 
                        WHERE dp.division_id = A.division_id 
                          AND dp.process_id < A.process_id) AS rnk
                 FROM erp_divisionProcess dp) X 
           ON X.division_id = d.division_id
    LEFT JOIN erp_BusinessProcess p ON p.process_id = X.process_id 
) Y
GROUP BY rnk');
```

Once view is created, you can issue a `select * from view_name` to fetch data into client.

**Demo** @ [*MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd33e/1)

Comment: But the select query for the view contains a subquery which is disallowed is MySQL. Also the beginning part of my prepared statement is dynamically building the cases for the column names in the pivoted result which I also thought wasn't allowed in a view.

Comment: Ok. You should better create a stored procedure with the code you have and `call sp` from your client app.